# How to build a demo for a Web Dashboard App in 28 days?

Tags: python, django, web, bootstrap-4

**Here is my situation:**
I need to present a demo of an online dashboard app at the beginning of January.

**Skills**: I know some Python (especially the data science frameworks) but have not yet worked with Django / flask or other languages than Python.

**Goal:** The app does not have to have many features. Mainly: login and data visualization, maybe some filters like date or category. It especially needs to LOOK good but can involve some parts being hard-coded.

**My first approach:** I saw bootstrap templates that look good already but is using Django with such templates the most efficient way for only a demo? There is some excellent way that may not even involve extensive coding but still offers some flexibility regarding page elements?

Thank you for your advice!

Comment: If you need to make the app fast, django is the best solution, if you use flask you will spend more time for the same result

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to Luiz' comment. Django has everything for you at your fingertips. I strongly recommend using django to make this project. One major reason I recommend Django is because they are the first ones to really jump on any new Security Risks and make sure Django doesn't ever run into them.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is **django**, since the user management is implicit within the framework, for the graphics you can use **ChartJs** and as for html style use **Bootstrap4** , all of them are very easy to integrate into Django and there is a lot of information, in 2 weeks you have it all.